# Renaming mulitple files from bottom to top? C#

Tags: c#, image, rename

i have put together this code which renames all the files in a folder in numeric order. What i want to do is make the last image have the name "1", 2nd to last image be named "2" if you catch my drift. im not sure how to do it. i have this so far

```
try
{
    string Path = @"C:\Users\William\Pictures\Documents\Apple iPhone\";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Path);
    FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
    int i = 1;

    string path;

    foreach (FileInfo fri in fiArr)
    {
        path = Path + i.ToString() + ".jpg";

        fri.MoveTo(path);

        i++;

    }
}
catch { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
    string Path = @"C:\Users\William\Pictures\Documents\Apple iPhone\";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Path);
    FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");

    for (var i = fiArr.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        var fri = fiArr[i - 1];
        var path = Path + i.ToString() + ".jpg";

        fri.MoveTo(path);
    }
}
catch { }
```

Comment: The order of the array returned by `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` is **NOT** guaranteed.  On `NTFS` filesystems this is, *for the moment*, alphabetical.  On other filesystems this is not the case.  [The order of the array is an implementation detail subject to change.]